# function in php that uses curl gives 404 when passing url as a variable, but gives 200(ok) result when passing string

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get and save an image from a webpage to my pc, but when I pass its url by grabbing it form page and save it in variable. and pass that variable to my curl image fetch function it returns 404.
But when I print that grabbed url variable and pass that printed value of variable to function by copy pasting , it returns 200(OK) and saves the image.

Here is my code:

```
preg_match('/id=\"searchForm:j_idt40\" src=\"(.*?)\"/', open('http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/restricted/PAS/StolenBoats.jsf'), $matches);
$url2= "http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us".$matches[1];
echo $url2;
grab_image($url2,"image2.jpg");
function open($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "1");   //writes cookie
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/restricted/PAS/StolenBoats.jsf');    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
function get_web_page( $url )
    {
        $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

        $options = array(

            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
            CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        $code=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        echo"<br>resp code:".$code;
        curl_close( $ch );
        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header['content'] = $content;
        return $header;
    }
function grab_image($url1,$save) {

echo"<br>#########################################################<br>";
echo"URL=".$url1;
    $result = get_web_page($url1);
    echo"<br>Errorno:".$result['errno'];
    echo"<br>Error msg:".$result['errmsg'];
    echo"<br>Content:".$result['content'];
    if(file_exists($save)){
        unlink($save);
    }
    $fp = fopen($save,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $result['content']);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Output to this is:

```
http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.jsf;jsessionid=yJ3Orpy4CG94G60BI1kpm43CSmuV8TYUOFa3IRr_.MEGADETHPRIMARY?ln=primefaces&v=6.1.2&pfdrid=558b6b95c559b790d2a10e03dbb80110&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=431a2d2a-970e-4584-9c6b-c7f88fb30b38
#########################################################
URL=http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.jsf;jsessionid=yJ3Orpy4CG94G60BI1kpm43CSmuV8TYUOFa3IRr_.MEGADETHPRIMARY?ln=primefaces&v=6.1.2&pfdrid=558b6b95c559b790d2a10e03dbb80110&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=431a2d2a-970e-4584-9c6b-c7f88fb30b38
resp code:404
Errorno:0
Error msg:
Content:
#########################################################
```

var_dump($url) results are:

```
dump before calling function:
string(297) "http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.jsf;jsessionid=QoecD0pG5uUUzXKOtMalTPJQhVu8ZkZFN7Y2VWYo.MEGADETHPRIMARY?ln=primefaces&v=6.1.2&pfdrid=558b6b95c559b790d2a10e03dbb80110&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=f15b2a89-ae8e-49d5-ac70-933c026b1ecb" 

dump before curl execution inside function
string(297) "http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.jsf;jsessionid=QoecD0pG5uUUzXKOtMalTPJQhVu8ZkZFN7Y2VWYo.MEGADETHPRIMARY?ln=primefaces&v=6.1.2&pfdrid=558b6b95c559b790d2a10e03dbb80110&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=f15b2a89-ae8e-49d5-ac70-933c026b1ecb" 
resp code:404

dump after curl:
string(297) "http://pas.fdle.state.fl.us/pas/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.jsf;jsessionid=QoecD0pG5uUUzXKOtMalTPJQhVu8ZkZFN7Y2VWYo.MEGADETHPRIMARY?ln=primefaces&v=6.1.2&pfdrid=558b6b95c559b790d2a10e03dbb80110&pfdrt=sc&pfdrid_c=false&uid=f15b2a89-ae8e-49d5-ac70-933c026b1ecb"
```

Comment: Have you done a comparison between the variable and what you expect it to be? var_dump($var === 'your expected string')?

Comment: Actually I tried that but that doesn't help as url is dynamic every time  I compare copied string to variable the variable has changed.

Comment: That doesn't what?

Comment: but if I pass that copied string to function it saves my image

Comment: The point that I am trying to raise is that obviously somewhere along the path of execution the url is broken or changed. If you add in var_dump($url) everywhere you will likely see where its being changed.

Comment: I tried var_dump($url) but I see no changes in url..I am posting var_dump results in question edit